# How to setup Visual Studio Code to debug C programs on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am trying to debug a `C` program in Visual Studio Code.
In my directory I have 2 files `test.c` and `Makefile` along with `.vscode` folder which contains `launch` and `tasks` json files.
I tried configuring these files for the last three hours searching various forums and blogs but nothing seems to work.

I am able to compile and run using these two json files.
Program runs and displays output correctly but doesn't stop at breakpoints, during execution of the program I can't add breakpoints and already added breakpoints are disabled with following message.

> Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.

It seems that VSCode is not able to locate my `test.c` file during debugging phase even though it is in the same directory. It will be great if someone can show me the right way to do it.
Here, I am attaching contents of files in my folder.
`launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "tasks",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "tasks",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`Makefile`

```
all:
    gcc test.c -o ./test
```

`test.c`

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Mandar\n");
    printf("Sadye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your configuration is correct except for one tiny thing: you forgot to pass the [`-g`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) flag to `gcc`.  Consequently, the `test` program does not have debugging information in it, and therefore `gdb` does not know the relationship between the source code and the compiled program.

Also, targets in a `Makefile` should specify what files they depend on.  Your `all` target does not have a dependency on `test.c`, so changing the source code will not cause recompilation.

Here is a fixed `Makefile`:

```
all: test

test: test.c
        gcc -g test.c -o ./test
```

With that fix, I am able to compile and debug this program on Linux using VSCode 1.36.1.